# marathon rest api returns no data

Tags: high-availability, marathon

I have 3 marathon servers running in HA. when i reach the rest api on the leader, it returns good data. But when i try it against one of the non leader nodes, I do not get any data back...no strings at all. The headers say 200...but no data. Has anybody experienced this before?

here is what i see on the leader

```
# curl -i http://10.0.0.1:8080/v2/apps
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Marathon-Leader: http://x1-master-0:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Type: application/json; qs=2
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

{"apps":[]}
```

here is the data from the non leader

```
# curl -i http://10.0.0.2:8080/v2/apps
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

Comment: Which Marathon version are you using?

Comment: Also, what does `curl -i http://x1-master-0:8080/v2/apps` give you from the host on which the queried non-leader Marathon instance is running?

Comment: Thanks Michael, that was it. marathon version is 0.10.1.
the other marathon servers could not resolve the leader by name...adding to /etc/hosts on the other servers made them reply with data.

Comment: Cool. I suggest you answer yourself, below (that is, describe the solution) for future reference and that others benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that the marathon servers could not resolve each other by name. Adding the hostnames of the other marathon servers to each marathon's /etc/hosts file fixed the problem.